# Auto copy ssh key on successful ssh password login

Tags: ssh

Is it possible to auto copy my ssh key after a successful first time ssh login with password ?

In other words :

when I type :

> ssh user@host

for the first time to that host and I successfully enter the right password I get my ssh key automatically copied to that host without the need to do : `copy-ssh-key` command manually

Comment: Would be great if there was a way to do this. If you have a large list of servers you don't know which one you will want to copy to until you actually need to log in there. Having to do 2 commands instead of one for each new server is a pain.

Comment: Something like `ssh me@host 'cat "'$(~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub)'" > ~/.ssh/known_hosts ; exec $SHELL'` would work but the problem is you'd get the same line duplicated in the server's known_hosts file every time you log in.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to add your public key to `authorized_keys` on a remote machine, an answer may be `ssh-copy-id` (e.g. part of `openssh-clients`).

Comment: Thank you for your answer : I know this command. what I want to do is that when I type : ssh user@host and I enter my password I get my ssh key copied automatically.

Comment: I think tonioc is suggesting run this command once for every new host you logon to `ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub user@remote-host`.